# How to move value from .data to register in NASM?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I'm a beginner in assembly language. I try to multiply two numbers.

```
section .data
a dw 1;
b dw 2;
global _start 

section .text
_start:
mov eax, [a];
mov ebx, [b];
movv:
mul ebx;
mull:

mov eax, 1;
mov ebx, 0;
int 80h;
```

I compile and run it with the following command:  `nasm -g -f elf pr1.s && ld -m elf_i386 pr1.o -o pr1 && gdb ./pr1` 
When I in gdb view the register eax value I get 131073 and ebx 65538
Why I get this values instead of 1 and 2?

**Edit about duplicate**

In duplicated question the author mostly asks about meaning of `db`, `dw`, `dd` operations, while in this question is being asked how to solve particular error. Nevertheless, duplicate question also useful for extended information about size of variables in assembly.

Comment: `mov eax, [a]` loads 4 bytes, but `a`is only two bytes. Use `movzx eax, word [a]` instead.

Comment: `a` and `b` are words, but you're doing doubleword reads. Either change `dw` to `dd`, or change `mov` to `movzx eax, word [a]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments, Michael answered on my question, changing dw to dd solved the problem.